# 403 forbidden error and html meta tags

Tags: php, html, apache, meta-tags, http-status-code-403

I am using php/mysql with apache 2 server.

I have a php data entry form which use a `<textarea>` html tag.

I usually enter some meta tags like 'description' or 'keywords' and when i save the form, the textarea save in a mysql textarea fieald at my database.

There was no problem for a long days, but a few days ago when i try to save data entry form, it generates 403 forbidden error.

There is something strange on it. If i enter only one meta tag like
`<meta name="description"...>` in textarea, there is no problem, but if i press the 'Enter' key and  add the 2nd tag like `<meta name="keywords"...>` in textarea, and press 'save' key,it generates the error.

Surprizingly, if i write a letter between two line tags like

`<meta name="description"...>A<meta name="keywords"...>`, it accepts again and save it to the database.

I contacted to my admin server and tell about misconfiguration about `mod_security` settings on the apache server, but they think it is not the problem.

Many thanks

Comment: At first *wild guess* it sounds like a [mod_security](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10864238/mod-security-is-sometimes-blocking-my-ajax-script-how-can-i-find-out-why) problem.

Answer (score 1):

I could not find the reason,but i could find a solution.

I manually added an useless character like char(255) to the start or end of the string.

String, means `<meta name="description"...>` or, `<meta name="keywords"...>`.

When i wanted to save the string in my database, simply deleted this character with

```
$string = str_replace(char(255),'',$string);
```

and surprizingly!...everything will be ok and it accepts $string!!!

Many Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

check the permissions of your www or public_html directories.