# Uploading large file (45MB) via AJAX failing

Tags: php, ajax, apache, laravel-5, fastcgi

I'm trying to upload files via AJAX. Small files ~10MB are being uploaded successfully.

However, when I try to upload larger files, it fails with the following message:

> Internal Server Error
>
> The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was
>   unable to complete your request.
>
> Please contact the server administrator, webmaster@.com and inform
>   them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might have done
>   that may have caused the error.
>
> More information about this error may be available in the server error
>   log.
>
> Additionally, a 500 Internal Server Error error was encountered while
>   trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

I'm using `Laravel 5` on dreamhost.

I've put debugging messages everywhere, but it seems that my PHP code is not being executed at all. Also, there's no info in error.log either.

I've checked `php.ini` with following settings:

```
max_execution_time 30
max_file_uploads 20
post_max_size 500M
upload_max_filesize 500M
```

Intially, I had mounted `/tmp folder` at one place which had partition size of 100MB. At that time, the error.log said `"modsecurity: input filter failed writing 8192 bytes to temporary file"`
So I changed to location of `/tmp` folder to my home folder in order to remove size restrictions, but not working.

Here is the current behaviour:
File upload shows 100%.
Then the request waits for sometime without causing logs.
After a while, the above mentioned error message is returned.

Let me know which further info is required.

Thank you very much!

Comment: `500 Internal Server` Means that you have php error in your page that you try to run

Comment: I understand that. That's why I've included the actual error.log message :)
I manage 404 etc from Laravel. What I am unable to debug is the file upload.

Comment: Is the tmp/ directory you are trying to upload to filled up? I think ModSecure has a file size limit for the tmp directory of 128MB to prevent the filesystem from being filled up.

Comment: I have emptied it completely.

Comment: To update, error.log is now displaying errors! I don't know when it starts displaying errors though.
Most recent error is:
`ModSecurity: Input filter: Failed writing 1452 bytes to temporary file (rc 200)`

Comment: @DavidDomain I checked mod_sec.conf. The value of `SecRequestBodyLimit` is `536870912`
That should work right?

Comment: Where does the following setting in your mod_sec.conf point to `SecTmpDir` ?

Comment: `SecUploadDir` is `/tmp` and `SecTmpDir` is `/tmp`. The file is write protected for me. And there are many files containing modsec config it seems. The Settings (secuploaddir and sectmpdir) I found were in a file named modsecurity_crs_10_config.conf

Also, the location of `SecTmpDir` differs from my setting of php.ini settings. As I have mentioned, I've mounted the `tmp` to another location now.

Comment: I should add that in the previous config when `tmp` was mounted at `/tmp`, I was unable to upload 45MB file. The allowed size of `tmp` directory was 100MB and the file I'm uploading is of 45MB. I assumed that may be mod_security and php both are trying to write in the same directory and might be causing the problem. I'll update after I get write access to the config.

Comment: @DavidDomain I got this thought - if it was a problem due to mod_security's location of tmp directory, why am I able to upload smaller files (~10MB)?

Comment: @Dhavan in your quiestion you said you changed the location of your tmp folder.

Comment: @DavidDomain I researched it further. Apparently, php.ini uploads to the changed path. But `/tmp` also exists. And is getting filled up. Thanks!

Comment: @DavidDomain I've disabled `mod_security`. Now the problem is, apache is still uploading files in `/tmp` instead of `/home/user/tmp` even though I've specified the path in `php.ini` and can confirm in `phpinfo()`. I'm on dreamhost. Can you help? Or should I create another question for it?

Answer (score 0):

For such issues, You should play with few parameters of php.ini.

1. max_execution_time
2. max_input_time
3. post_max_size
4. upload_max_filesize

Try to keep max_execution_time and max_input_time to ZERO (0).

It won't bound your execution to 30 seconds.

Hope this helps!!

Comment: Okay. I am going to try `max_execution` time and input_time with 0.

Comment: Changed `max_execution_time` to 0.
Changed `max_input_time` to -1
I think `post_max_size` and `upload_max_size` values of 500MB are sufficient for a 45MB file.

Still getting the following error in error.log:
`ModSecurity: Input filter: Failed writing 1452 bytes to temporary file (rc 1144)`

Comment: Is it helpful? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10864238/mod-security-is-sometimes-blocking-my-ajax-script-how-can-i-find-out-why

Comment: Yes, we are going through similar process in the comments of the question! :D
I'm stuck till I get write permission to change mod_security config