# AJAX File Upload Error 500 with 20MB size file

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, file, spring-mvc

I am trying to upload a file using AJAX Post, but I am getting 500 error when trying to upload a 10Mb file, but uploading a 5Mb file if it works fine.

[image]

[image]

[image]

JS:

```
function subirArchivos() {
  var formSubirArchivo = $('#frmSubirArchivo')[0];
  var dataSubirArchivo = new FormData(formSubirArchivo);
  $.ajax({
    url: base + '/solicitud?accion=subirDocumento',
    type: "POST",
    enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
    data: dataSubirArchivo,
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    cache: false,
    timeout: 60000, //60seg to try!
    success: function(data) {
    ...
    },
    error: function() {
        ...
    }
  });
}
```

HTML:

```
<form method="POST" id="frmSubirArchivo" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="hidden" id="idDocumentoSdu" name="idDocumentoSdu"/>
..
  <input type="file" id="file" name="file" style="display: none;">
..
<div class="modal-footer">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-mdl-subir-archivos" onclick="subirArchivos()">Aceptar <i class="fa-fa-check"></i></button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-mdl-subir-archivos" data-dismiss="modal" onclick="cancelarModalSubirArchivos()">Cancelar <i class="fa fa-times"></i></button>
</div>
```

Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(params = { "accion=subirDocumento" }, value = { "/solicitud" }, method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public Map<String, Object> subirDocumento(HttpServletRequest request, @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file,
    @RequestParam("idDocumentoSdu") String idDocumentoSdu,
                             ....) {
    ...
}
```

Config:

```
@Bean(name="multipartResolver")
public CommonsMultipartResolver multipartResolver(){
    CommonsMultipartResolver commonsMultipartResolver=new CommonsMultipartResolver();
    commonsMultipartResolver.setResolveLazily(true);
    commonsMultipartResolver.setMaxUploadSize(20971520);  //20Mb
    commonsMultipartResolver.setMaxUploadSizePerFile(20971520); //20Mb
    return commonsMultipartResolver;
}
```

Comment: Try adjusting the encryption time. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30475772/uploading-large-file-45mb-via-ajax-failing this could be useful, even though it's with php the comments seem to have good suggestions.

Comment: what web server you are using? glashfish, apache, ?

Comment: jboss 7.2, i checked the log and the message is: "org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartException: Failed to parse multipart servlet request; nested exception is org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadException: UT000020: Connection terminated as request was larger than 10485760".